# Max value in Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Need some help finding the max value in a worksheet,

I tried with range:

```
Dim maxNumber As Double 
maxNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A1:B5"))
```

Except I don't want it to stop at B5, I want it to go through the whole Worksheet.

So I found that "XFD1048576" symbolizes the last cell of a worksheet:

```
Dim maxNumber As Double 
maxNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A1:XFD1048576"))
```

Just wondering now if there's a more elegant solution, anything to replace "XFD1048576", or simply writing better code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the ["UsedRange"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221970%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property?

Your code example would then become something like:

```
Dim maxNumber As Double  
maxNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange)
```

You can also use the [Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb148836%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property - `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells` to search every cell, even if it's empty. For this reason, I'd prefer to use UsedRange.

Comment: would suggest adding a condition to test for no numeric values - esle 0 will be returned for a empty sheet, or a sheet with text only